# Error while creating security group in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am creating security group and allowing inbound protocol for TCP and HTTP to open for all ips using below code:

```
IpPermission ipPermission = new IpPermission();

        ipPermission.withIpRanges("0.0.0.0/0")
                        .withIpProtocol("tcp")
                        .withFromPort(22)
                        .withToPort(22);
        ipPermission.withIpRanges("0.0.0.0/0")
        .withIpProtocol("http")
        .withFromPort(80)
        .withToPort(80);
            AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest authorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest =
                    new AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest();

                authorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest.withGroupName("JavaSecurityGroup")
                                                    .withIpPermissions(ipPermission);
                amazonEC2Client.authorizeSecurityGroupIngress(authorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest);
```

However, it is giving me below error:
Invalid value 'http' for IP protocol. Unknown protocol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http is not a valid **IP** protocol.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/IpPermission.html#withIpProtocol(java.lang.String)

use TCP, UDP or ICMP